# Image assets in css Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

Ok, so I have problem with linking assets ang using path to image in css.
I have assets in src\AppBundle\Resources\public\ I did assets:install and assetic:dump, but I can't link both image and css correctly.

Here is my layout.twig.html from AppBundle\Resources\views

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerfontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" />
      {% endstylesheets %}
```

and my config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ "AppBundle" ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

and finally here is my css with background image

```
   background: url('../images/nav_bg.jpg') repeat;
```

It all works on dev but my main.css from assets is not visible in prod environment however fontawesome link is ok. Path to css in prod env is `/web/css/2c8c367.css`.
When it should be `web/bundles/app/css/2c8c367.css`
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: try run both commands with `--env=prod` option

Comment: you are welcome, should I make it as an answer or leave it in comments?

Comment: make it an answer, maybe it will help someone else and answers are more visible